# Ghosting input in the terminal prompt

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2

I am using iTerm on OS X.

When I press up arrow key to look for the input in the history, and edit from there, I sometimes see the ghosting input.

```
$vvi .bash_prompt
```

The first v is ghosting input.

How can I resolve this?

See my .bash_prompt

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
export TERM=xterm-color

parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

export PS1="\[\033[38;5;241m\]\w\[$(tput sgr0)\]\
[\033[38;5;15m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\\n   \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

Comment: Does it also happen without that emoji in your prompt?

Comment: @usr2564301 Problem solved after removing emoji. Thanks for your suggestion